# To what extent does splitting a virus into different files reduce the chance of detection by VirusTotal?

Tags: virus

I have a 60 MB file that I want to scan for viruses. VirusTotal's max file size is 20MB. If I zip the 60 MB file into 3 smaller chunks and upload each of them to VirusTotal, to what extent will it reduce the chances of detection by VirusTotal in case it is contains a virus?

Comment: Splitting the file will make any scanning attempt useless.  Virustotal does identification based on the signature of the file.

Comment: Actually the max size is 64 MiB: http://i.imgur.com/t25GGAy.png The chances of a splitted file being properly detected entirely depends on the actual file content. If you split e.g. an executable, the first chunk actually *looks* like one, albeit broken; not so for the rest. If the file is an archive you could extract it and analyze each file manually. However, the archived files might be a lot, or become bigger than the limit once uncompressed. Another alternative is to create a virtual machine, install each antivirus engine used by VirusTotal, and manually scan the file yourself.

Comment: I think that the reason for the file size limit in VirusTotal (as well as Anti-Viruses) is that usually viruses tend to be small so they take less attention and be able to spread easily. Also, they usually do quite simple actions, so they don't need many code lines.